# How to save current state of canvas as an image in android

Tags: android

I'm developing an application which allows user to edit an image and save that edited image as new image on sd card I want to get the current state of the canvas object.
please help me with this.

Comment: Please post the code that you are trying...

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer without knowing more about how your image editor works. I will guess that it is a SurfaceView, which is commonly subclassed to allow arbitrary drawing.

SurfaceView provides an easy way to render the output to canvas and thus a bitmap.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mSurfaceView.getWidth(), mSurfaceView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
mSurfaceView.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
try {
    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(saved.png));
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.w(TAG, e);
}
```